# Is the tag `statistical-confidence` portmanteau of `confidence-interval` and `statistical-significance` and should it be deleted?

Tags: discussion, tag-reorganization, tag-deletion

Update: I've re-tagged all questions tagged with [statistical-confidence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-confidence).

---

I came across a question tagged [statistical-confidence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-confidence): [Find the confidence in an accuracy measurement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/582751/find-the-confidence-in-an-accuracy-measurement). I interpreted it as a question about [statistical-significance](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-significance), so I made an edit.

Then I looked at the [statistical-confidence](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/statistical-confidence) tag. It doesn't have a description. There are only 24 (now 22) questions tagged with it, all within the last year.

- Should this tag be deleted and the question re-tagged with `statistical-significance` instead, if appropriate?
- What's the procedure when one comes across a (potentially) unwise tag like this example?

This question from 2015 seems related: [Ambiguous [confidence] tag](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2613/ambiguous-confidence-tag)

Comment: I edited to make the tags clickable!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*(Turning my comment into an answer)*

Nearly half (13/22) have either `[sc]` & `[ci]`, or `[sc]` & `[ss]`.  That's prima facie evidence that it's seen as strongly related to those tags and just adding some nuance in the OP's mind.  The others I'd have to look at, but I strongly suspect something better could be found in each case.  I think we should remove and/or retag them, and then `[sc]` will just disappear.

Comment: Done! I've retagged all the questions that were labeled [tag:statistical-confidence]. Also learned that there are some uncategorizable questions on CV.